# update $stateParams in ui-router after $location.search() is called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ionic-framework

I have an angular application which is using the ionic-framework, which uses ui-router on the back end.

In one of my controllers I call:

```
$location.search('filter','sometext');
```

I have reloadOnSearch disabled in my routing configuration. I noticed that updating the location does not update the `$stateParams`.  Is there a way to force the `$stateParams` to update as the location is updated?  I looked through the ui-router documentation, but didn't see anything about this scenario, but perhaps I missed it.

Comment: I found `$urlRouter.sync()` but that does not update the state params after the $location has been updated.

Comment: When are you using the sync()? `$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeSuccess', function(evt) { $urlRouter.sync(); });`

Comment: This is verified bug.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1546

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had a similar situation. You cannot track route updates if you had disabled `reloadOnSearch`, but I found a solution for this case.

Watch `$stateParams`:

```
$scope.$watchCollection('$stateParams', function (newParams) {
    var search = $location.search();

    if (angular.isObject(newParams)) {
      angular.extend(search, newParams);
    }

    $location.search(search).replace();
});
```

Change `$stateParams`, not route:

```
$scope.$stateParams.offset += $scope.$stateParams.limit;
```

Completely [working example](http://github.com/dnemoga/application-client).