# get angular ui router $location.search() to use Basic URL Parameters

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I have ui-router set up as follows

```
.state('root.event', {
    url : '/event/:id',
    templateUrl : 'templates/event.html'
})
```

(the controller is initiated in the template)

which gives nice looking [Basic URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#basic-parameters) like:
`www.mysite.com/event/1234`

When a user navigates ***directly*** to my `www.mysite.com/event` path (ie param is missing) the template controller looks the most recent `id` parameter from either:
- a js variable stored in a value
- localstorage / cookie etc

I then return this to my state using `$location.search('id', 1234)`

...however, this results in URLs which have [Query URL Parameters](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing#query-parameters) like:
`www.mysite.com/event/?id=1234`

Is there a technique to ensure that `$stateparams` updates present the url in basic format on update ?

...or is it possible to get the URL parameter & update the `$state` before the state change  ?
(I looked at [Resolve](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#resolve) but this seems mostly to be about passing parameters to controllers)

I've had a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24622120), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26953627) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20884551) - but most of the questions relate to how to avoid reload on update of $state params

Answer (score 1):

`$location.search` does exactly that. It adds query URL parameter. I think what you're looking for is

```
$state.go('root.event', {id: 1234})
```

Comment: won't that reload the template rather than just updating the parameters ?